# Rendering polygons ordered by size in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, dissolve, order

How can I merge shapefiles in a special order in QGIS?
What I have and what I need to be merged in that order:

[image: what i have]

What happens when using merge by MMQGIS:

[image: merged by mmqgis]

As u can see not usable at all. Attributes are gone.

What happens when i use "merge shapefiles" tool by QGIS:

[image: merge shapefiles by qgis]

As u can see some time zones are covering smaller time zones. So i tried to order them by using MMQGIS again:

[image: sort merged shapefiles by qgis by mmqgis]

Attributes are ordered now but geometry is still overlapping.

Is it possible to merge shapefiles in a special order using QGIS respectively to sort their geometry afterwards?

Comment: You need them to display with the smallest coverage geometries on top correct? If that's right then you can change the display order using symbol levels (https://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most data providers do not guarantee any order in the way they deliver features. While an apparently stable order is often a side effect of the order in which features are stored in files, one shouldn't rely on this.

Therefore I'll re-interpret the question as "how can features be rendered in a given order within QGIS".

To do this, open the layer properties, head to the *Symbology* tab, scroll down to the *Layer rendering* group box on this page, where you find a *Control feature rendering order* checkbox. Once this is checked, there is a *A->Z* button on which you can define which attribute(s) should define the sort order and if it should be in descending or ascending order.

For your case, entering `"time"` as sort order expression might be good. Or, if you want smaller areas on top of bigger areas, use `$area`.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `Union` Tool from `Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Union`. This should give you the correct topology. Or, you can use `difference` tool repeatedly to get the difference between big polygons and smallers polygons and finally use `Merge` tool to put them in one polygon shapefile.

But `Union` will solve the problem.

Comment: union works as well. unfortunately i cannot mark more than one answer as accepted. but of course this one is as well. difference tool is what i was using so far to bypass the problem.

Comment: No problem at all, but you can still upvote the answer if you did not do so. Good luck :)