# Dissolving isochrones from point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, dissolve, polygon-creation, isochrone

I have created a set of isochrones (3, 5, 10 minute walk times) from a point layer. I now want to dissolve the layer to make it more readable. However when I try to dissolve based on the field that specifies walk times I do not get the result I want. I have a pretty clear example I am trying to imitate but they do not explain how they did it.

I want to go from this:
[image: before dissolved isochrones]

To this:
[image: after dissolved isochrones]

However, when I try dissolve and select the MINS field as the dissolve field I get this:
[image: wrong output]

Is there a way to do this in one step? I know I could select the polygon from the isochrones layer for each distance (3, 5, 10 mins) and then dissolve only selected features but I am looking for a way to do this in one step with the dissolve tool. Is this possible or should i just stick with the slower method of selecting and then dissolving individually?

Comment: Have you checked this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279825/cutting-polygons-in-same-isochrone-map-layer?rq=1?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the attribute table? Are the missing isochrones below/covered by the others?

Comment: Looks pretty correct. I guess its just a matter of render order. Take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263130/render-polygons-ordered-by-size

Answer (score 0):

first, select all yellow polygons and do `union`. second, select all the blue ones and do `union`.and lastly for the gray ones.

Now you should have three features. Then give a unique attribute to each. e.g. `unionYellow = 0 , unionBlue = 1, unionGray = 2` then use `merge shapefiles` tool or any other merger tool. You can use the numbers to change their order. Now you are ready to go. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

For such tasks, the [Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate) function is an easy way to do it: `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate`.

Use the field that specifies walk times as input for `Group by expression`, define the desired `Aggregate function` for each field (or delete fields you don't use) and run the tool.